# Affordable way to install shade sail to rental balcony

Tags: post

[image]I have a pretty large balcony, maybe 20'x 6, its part of a rental and south facing.

I'd like to install shade sails without drilling any holes. Is this an impossible task?

My balcony has metal railing, perhaps theres a way to affix poles to those?

Comment: Some pictures of the balcony, the surrounding walls and railings would be very helpful. We have no idea how it's all set up and what to recommend.

Comment: @GregNickoloff added a pic. its a townhouse

Comment: Have you checked with the management or owners about this? They might object.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try tying the sail down, but can only guess to what! Wind acting on a sail can generate a lot of pull, so think it through carefully.Try getting some braided Dacron cord. It feels soft and is pretty strong.
2. Maybe you could come up with a lightweight frame for the sail that can be erected just as you go to use it. Make a framework with pvc (white) or cpvc (black) pipes and fittings. Only use cement on some parts and a slip fit on others so it’s easy to take down and store in the corner/against the wall. If you use sections of sail instead of one big sheet it might look better and be easier to deal with. Good luck.

Comment: thanks! i added a pic for detail. What about tying down two ends to the front rails and the other 2 ends to weighted poles ?

Comment: @mugetsu - Maybe. Sure would get ugly quick if the wind grabs that sail and snaps those weighted poles off the balcony....